Failed to build spring-boot 3.2.x
I used ./gradlew format clean publishToMavenLocal -x test &\> log to build the spring-boot 3 from
source code.
And it failed with:


Workers waiting for work: 4
Stopped workers: 1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Unable to make progress running work. There are items queued for execution but none of them can be started

Try:



Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation
warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See
https://docs.gradle.org/7.6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
Execution optimizations have been disabled for 96 invalid unit(s) of
work during this build to ensure correctness. Please consult
deprecation warnings for more details.
BUILD FAILED in 6m 11s 801 actionable tasks: 798 executed, 1 from
cache, 2 up-to-date
A build scan was not published as you have not authenticated with
server 'ge.spring.io'. For more information, please see
https://gradle.com/help/gradle-authenticating-with-gradle-enterprise.

I've searched for this issue, but it seems like no one has encountered it.
build.gradle
plugins {
    id "base"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" apply false // https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30276
    id "io.spring.nohttp" version "0.0.11"
}

description = "Spring Boot Build"

defaultTasks 'build'

nohttp {
    allowlistFile = project.file("src/nohttp/allowlist.lines")
    source.exclude "**/bin/**"
    source.exclude "**/build/**"
    source.exclude "**/out/**"
    source.exclude "**/target/**"
    source.exclude "**/.settings/**"
    source.exclude "**/.classpath"
    source.exclude "**/.project"
    source.exclude "spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-buildpack-platform/src/test/resources/org/springframework/boot/buildpack/platform/docker/export.tar"
}

check {
    dependsOn checkstyleNohttp
}

allprojects {
    group "org.springframework.boot"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        if (version.contains('-')) {
            maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        }
        if (version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')) {
            maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        }
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, "minutes"
    }
}

tasks.named("checkstyleNohttp").configure {
    maxHeapSize = "1536m"
}

openjdk version "17-internal" 2021-09-14 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17-internal+0-adhoc.root.crac) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17-internal+0-adhoc.root.crac, mixed mode, sharing)
------------------------------------------------------------ Gradle 7.6.4 ------------------------------------------------------------ Build time: 2024-02-05 14:29:18 UTC Revision: e0bb3fc8cefad8432c9033cdfb12dc14facc9dd9 Kotlin: 1.7.10 Groovy: 3.0.13 Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023 JVM: 17-internal (Oracle Corporation 17-internal+0-adhoc.root.crac) OS: Linux 5.15.0-051500-generic amd64

Please provide build.gradle and the output of java -version, ./gradlew -version

openjdk version "17-internal" 2021-09-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17-internal+0-adhoc.root.crac)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17-internal+0-adhoc.root.crac, mixed mode, sharing)


Gradle 7.6.4
Build time:   2024-02-05 14:29:18 UTC
Revision:     e0bb3fc8cefad8432c9033cdfb12dc14facc9dd9
Kotlin:       1.7.10
Groovy:       3.0.13
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          17-internal (Oracle Corporation 17-internal+0-adhoc.root.crac)
OS:           Linux 5.15.0-051500-generic amd64

The spring version is 3.2.4

I managed to build it skipping more tasks
./gradlew clean build -x test -x intTest -x systemTest -x downloadJdk

....

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 53s
3283 actionable tasks: 2001 executed, 636 from cache, 646 up-to-date



My environment
$ ./gradlew -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.6.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2024-02-05 14:29:18 UTC
Revision:     e0bb3fc8cefad8432c9033cdfb12dc14facc9dd9

Kotlin:       1.7.10
Groovy:       3.0.13
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          17 (Oracle Corporation 17+35-2724)
OS:           Linux 6.5.0-28-generic amd64


Thank you for your effort. I also managed to do it by removing the clean and configuring the proxy (China) as following.


Proxy
org.gradle.jvmargs=-DsocksProxyHost=192.168.31.53 -DsocksProxyPort=7890 
systemProp.http.proxyHost=192.168.31.53
systemProp.http.proxyPort=7890
systemProp.https.proxyHost=192.168.31.53
systemProp.https.proxyPort=7890

Replace the host and port. If your network is ok, just ignore this.

rm -rf ~/.gradle

Remove all .gradle and build in project

./gradlew --stop

Don't use clean
./gradlew format publishToMavenLocal


